# Найти значение выражения

Tags: c++, математика

Дано задание номер 8:[image: Уравнение]

И вот мой код:

```
//найти значение выражения
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    float X;
    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> X;
    if (X > 0 && X < 5) cout << "Корень из отрицательного числа\n";
    else if (X <=-2 && X<0) cout << "Логарифм отрицательного числа\n";
    else if (X == -3) cout << "Деление на ноль\n";
    else
    {
        float Y = (sqrt(X - 5 / X * X - 9)) + log((X * X + 2 * X + 1));
        cout << "F = " << Y << endl;

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

У меня проблема в проверках промежутков,кроме 4 ни одна из цифр ниже из таблицы не проходит.
Можете помочь пожалуйста с исправлением промежутков?

Comment: Самая важная информация, это номер задания?. Поэтому она у вас в самом начале вопроса?... Если X <=-2, то  проверка X<0 лишняя...

Comment: Самая важная информация в картинке,ведь там условие@ARHovsepyan

Comment: `X - 5 / X * X - 9` скобки забыли `(X - 5) / (X * X - 9)`

Comment: @AlexGlebe,в программе ниже я исправил.

Answer (score 3):

Порядок оценивания:

```
if (X * X == 9)
if ((X - 5) / (X * X - 9)) < 0      (обратите внимание на скобки в знаменателе)
if (X == -1)                    (то же, что и X*X + 2 * X + 1 <= 0)
```

Comment: я бы сказал " то же, что и X*X + 2 * X + 1 == 0",  (на отрицательность проверка лишняя)

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо,сейчас попробую ваше решение @MBo

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Имелась в виду такая логика - для логарифма нужно проверить на "неположительность" -  а в данном конкретном случае это сводится к не равно -1

Comment: Так,ваше реализация не работает,всё равно не проходят на проверку остальные цифры.@MBo

Answer (score 0):

В общем спасибо "за помощь" без обид только товарищи программисты.
Я написал верную программу:

```
//найти значение выражения
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    float X;
    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> X;
    if (X * X == 9) cout << "Деление на ноль\n";
    else if ((X - 5) / (X * X - 9) < 0) cout << "Корень из отрицательного числа\n";
    else if ((X * X + 2 * X + 1) <= 0) cout << "Логарифм неположительного числа\n";
    else
    {
        float Y = (sqrt((X - 5) / (X * X - 9))) + log((X * X + 2 * X + 1));
        cout << "F = " << Y << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Разве это не то, что я написал (последнее сравнение поправил сейчас)?